# Allow multiple file selection in dialog box, but send as individual POSTs to server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, jquery-ui-widget

I would like to POST individual files to Amazon S3 but allow the user to select multiple files in a single file selection.

I can successfully POST to S3 using single file selection, so I don't need any advice on that, but what I would like advice on is **how to split the individual file elements in the dialog selection box and then for each file send as an individual POST**.

I am using the [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin so if you can provide information relating to that it would be a plus, I'm sure.